# SQL Grouping table structure with conditional join advice

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables

1) `Photos  (PhotoId,Title, CreatedById,etc...)`

2) `Stories  (StotyId,StoryDesc,CoverPhotoId,CreatedById,etc...)`

3) `Groups (GroupId,GroupDesc,CreatedById)`

Now i want to create a table where i can store the contents of a Group. Each Group can have 1 or mroe Photos and Stories. How will i store that ? If i use only table like this

```
 GroupContents (Id,GroupId,ItemId,ItemType)
```

Where I will store StoryId or PhotoId in the ItemId column and store either "Story" or "Photo" in the ItemType column.

When i write a query to get contents of a Group,Should i add a conditinal join ? ie; If the ItemType is "Story" , Join from Story table, Else Join from Photos table ? Because same story id and PhotoId exist as its an Identity column in both tables

What is the best way to handle this scenario ?  Should i create 2 seperate tables like `GroupPhotos(GroupId,PhotoId)` and `GroupStories(GroupId,StoryId)` ?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to handle this scenario ? Should i create 2 seperate tables like GroupPhotos(GroupId,PhotoId) and GroupStories(GroupId,StoryId) ?

Yes, exactly.

Then you'd just do Group LEFT JOIN GroupPhotos LEFT JOIN GroupStories